# Custom exceptions are not raised properly when used in Multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x

### Question

I am observing behavior in Python 3.3.4 that I would like help understanding: Why are my exceptions properly raised when a function is executed normally, but not when the function is executed in a pool of workers?

### Code

```
import multiprocessing

class AllModuleExceptions(Exception):
    """Base class for library exceptions"""
    pass

class ModuleException_1(AllModuleExceptions):
    def __init__(self, message1):
        super(ModuleException_1, self).__init__()
        self.e_string = "Message: {}".format(message1)
        return

class ModuleException_2(AllModuleExceptions):
    def __init__(self, message2):
        super(ModuleException_2, self).__init__()
        self.e_string = "Message: {}".format(message2)
        return

def func_that_raises_exception(arg1, arg2):
    result = arg1 + arg2
    raise ModuleException_1("Something bad happened")

def func(arg1, arg2):

    try:
        result = func_that_raises_exception(arg1, arg2)

    except ModuleException_1:
        raise ModuleException_2("We need to halt main") from None

    return result

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
results = pool.starmap(func, [(1,2), (3,4)])

pool.close()
pool.join()

print(results)
```

This code produces this error:

> Exception in thread Thread-3:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "/user/peteoss/encap/Python-3.4.2/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()  
>   File "/user/peteoss/encap/Python-3.4.2/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 869, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>     File "/user/peteoss/encap/Python-3.4.2/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 420, in _handle_results
>       task = get()
>     File "/user/peteoss/encap/Python-3.4.2/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
>       return ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
>   TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message2'

Conversely, if I simply call the function, it seems to handle the exception properly:

```
print(func(1, 2))
```

Produces:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "exceptions.py", line 40, in 
>       print(func(1, 2))
>     File "exceptions.py", line 30, in func
>       raise ModuleException_2("We need to halt main") from None
>   __main__.ModuleException_2

Why does `ModuleException_2` behave differently when it is run in a process pool?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that your exception classes have non-optional arguments in their `__init__` methods, but that when you call the superclass `__init__` method you don't pass those arguments along. This causes a new exception when your exception instances are unpickled by the `multiprocessing` code.

This has been a long-standing issue with Python exceptions, and you can read quite a bit of the history of the issue in [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue1692335) (in which a part of the underlying issue with pickling exceptions was fixed, but not the part you're hitting).

To summarize the issue: Python's base `Exception` class puts all the arguments it's `__init__` method receives into an attribute named `args`. Those arguments are put into the `pickle` data and when the stream is unpickled, they're passed to the `__init__` method of the newly created object. If the number of arguments received by `Exception.__init__` is not the same as a child class expects, you'll get at error at unpickling time.

A workaround for the issue is to pass all the arguments you custom exception classes require in their `__init__` methods to the superclass `__init__`:

```
class ModuleException_2(AllModuleExceptions):
    def __init__(self, message2):
        super(ModuleException_2, self).__init__(message2) # the change is here!
        self.e_string = "Message: {}".format(message2)
```

Another possible fix would be to not call the superclass `__init__` method at all (this is what the fix in the bug linked above allows), but since that's usually poor behavior for a subclass, I can't really recommend it.

Comment: What if the custom exception is defined inside a third-party library? Is there a workaround that doesn't require changing the definition of the custom exception? I'm having the issue with `botocore.exceptions.ClientError`

Comment: I'm not aware of a good solution that could work without changing the exception type. You might be able to monkey-patch the library, or perhaps your worker code could catch the library's exception and raise a better behaved exception in its place? Otherwise, I'd suggest filing a bug report on the library.

Comment: As a side note: Don't use a property named `args` in your custom Exception classes!

Answer (score 2):

Your `ModuleException_2.__init__` fails while beeing unpickled.

I was able to fix the problem by changing the signature to

```
class ModuleException_2(AllModuleExceptions):
    def __init__(self, message2=None):
        super(ModuleException_2, self).__init__()
        self.e_string = "Message: {}".format(message2)
        return
```

but better have a look at [Pickling Class Instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) to ensure a clean implementation.